# Session Factory Creation Hibernate 5.0.7 using registry and metadata

Tags: hibernate

I have attached my code and its not creating sessionfactory at all, Please take a look at it and let me know where i went wrong.

**HibernateUtilities.java**

```
package com.yashwanth.HIbernate;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HIbernateUtilities {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public SessionFactory setUp() throws Exception
{

        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();

            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

        /*catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }*/
return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Here is another java class:

```
package com.yashwanth.HIbernate;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) throws HibernateException, Exception
    {
        System.out.println("yashpotu");
        HIbernateUtilities Utility =new HIbernateUtilities();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=Utility.setUp();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user=new User();
        user.setName("YASH");
        user.setGoal(250);
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
       }

       }

Here is the error:an 23, 2016 1:09:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306]
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sat Jan 23 13:09:35 EST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Jan 23, 2016 1:09:35 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.yashwanth.HIbernate.User]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:179)
    at com.yashwanth.HIbernate.HIbernateUtilities.setUp(HIbernateUtilities.java:48)
    at com.yashwanth.HIbernate.Program.main(Program.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.yashwanth.HIbernate.User
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 9 more
```

Thanks in advance, please let me know where I went wrong

Comment: Well, the message says: "Could not load requested class : org.yashwanth.HIbernate.User". Do you have that class in the classpath?

Comment: exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.yashwanth.HIbernate.User]

Comment: yes there is a problem loading the class itself

Comment: The two classes you've posted are in package `com.yashwanth.HIbernate`. But Hibernate is looking for the class User in the package `org.yashwanth.HIbernate`. org != com.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
       return new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable cause) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + cause);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(cause);
    }
```